# Can potential conflicts arise between IPtables port blocking and NAT port translation?

Tags: iptables, nat

I have set my iptables rules to open only some ports for outgoing connections. I also have snat iptables rules to do NAT which I presume will do a local IP to public IP and also a port translation, say for different browsers trying to access HTTP servers. The source ports of these browser requests are certainly unpredictable.

Is there anyway to restrict snat to map only to a given range of ports? Is there a way to limit browsers from using source port numbers from a certain port range only? Otherwise, all ports will have to be allowed for connections initiated from inside. Is that correct?

Comment: Why do you care about the source ports?

Comment: @Michael Hampton Just another security level, I think.  If applications are restricted to certain source port range, when initiating traffic, then implicitly one is providing application level control through iptables. App1(e.g. browser) uses range1 ports, App2 uses range2 ports, etc.  In iptables, apps are kind of restricted by destination ports and the transport protocol that they use. However, for example, app1, not a browser, using a random source port, tries to access a non-http-server listening on port 80 via a TCP connection, the iptables rules cannot see through this.